# Making own calendar for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, calendar, windows-phone

I am thinking of making my own calendar application for Windows Phone. I don't want to be tied up with the built in calendar as it has limitation like not being able to delete or edit. I have been researching for resources to help me get started. Is there a place where I could read on for starting my calendar application? Or any advice would help too

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience in making mobile applications? With this kind of app you want to plan it right, it's not very complicated but it might get so if you don't think about things like how to store your data before starting it.

You can also encounter some problems making alarms, which are a key to calendar apps. [MSDN has is covered here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have experience i android application. Windows is a new platform where i found that being tied with the built in calendar will limit the features of my app.
You are right about the alarms/reminder app which are also tied with the calendar. Which Is why im finding a way to overcome it.